# Start ID Column from Specific Number

Tags: column

Is there anyway to start the default ID column from specific number? For example start from 2151 instead of 1?
Or is there any way to fill the items with values in order to reach 2151 in ID field and then stop filling automatically?

Answer (score 2):

ID can not be changed, but you can create another column for this ID purpose but remember you cant use ID column in calculated field so I would suggest you to go for ItemAdded event receiver, and in the event receiver you can do something like

```
item["NewID"]=item.ID+2150;
```

You can also achieve this using workflow if you dont want to use event receiver for this purpose

Comment: One drawback to this is you won't be able to use hyperlink tricks, e.g., `.../DispForm.aspx?ID=`, as easily.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's possible to use the document id feature?
Here a link to a resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559302%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create column named ID. It is by default created by SharePoint itself. You cannot even rename it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can write a console application with a for cycle, which inserts 2150 entries into your list, then you can delete those entries. This way you will have an empty list where the standard ID column starts from 2151. But I suggest you do this only if you want to test some specific scenario in a test environment.

For a real business scenario, where you need a column that counts from 2151, you should consider something like @Diptarag's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following Norbet's advice, but instead of a console app, you could use an easy powershell script to loop through, add the item and then delete it. That'll get you to the ID number you want. It'll be taxing on SP/SQL (adding and removing) but it'll work.

However, I like Diptarag's advice more, just create a new field and perform the calculations your self.